# Custom music in Burnout Paradise

Tags: xbox-360, burnout-paradise

Is it possible to play custom music in Burnout Paradise ?
If so, how can I put music from my computer on the XBox and play it in the game
(I've grown tired of the built-in soundtrack)

Comment: I'd love to know if there a way to do this on the PC version.

Comment: @cowgod very easy: just turn off the music in-game. Then use your favourite music player in the background. Mine responds to my media keys so I can skip / pause / resume. Hurray for multi-tasking operating systems and PC gaming!

Comment: @romkyns That's a cop out!  It would be nice if it were better integrated like in GTA 3/VC/SA and Sims 2.

Comment: @cowgod I'm not sure what the benefit would be because I haven't played any of those. Is it the added realism or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtually all games on the Xbox don't let you change the soundtrack. You could hook a CD player up to your receiver, or something like that though.

Comment: In that case I can just turn on the music in my living room of course, but I get the point :-)

Comment: Also, you might be able to turn off the music in game, and just have the sound effects.

Answer (score 4):

You can play custom music in any Xbox game. The steps are:

1. Get the music onto your Xbox. The
   easiest way is, arguably, to rip the
   desired CDs to the hard drive.
2. Create a playlist of the music you
   like and save it to the hard disk.
3. Launch the game.
4. Bring up the
   system control panel by hitting the
   big green button, navigate over to
   the media tab, and start your
   playlist.

You can then go back to your game and listen to your own music. Of course, you'll have to fuss around with the sound effects/music balance in the game's audio settings to achieve the blend you like, but it's usually not that hard to do.

I think there's even an Xbox 101 video in the archives on this subject if you go look for it.

Comment: I'll give this a try

Comment: There are also brief instructions [here](http://support.xbox.com/en-us/pages/xbox-360/how-to/xbox-360-as-media-player/play-media-from-portable-media-player.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0); they can be a little confusing, though, because they're talking about playing a custom soundtrack but giving you instructions for playing it on a connected device (of course you've already covered playing a local playlist).